# Open a DataBase Connection within the try parenthesis?

Tags: database-connection

I want to know that is it useful to opan a connection inside parenthesis of try cause at the end there is no need to close that connection it happens automatically..... ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of defining a connection within a `using` statement is that the variable defined is automatically disposed at the end of the block. It is still good practice to explicitly `Close()` the connection when you're done using it. Like this in SQL Server:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(...)) {
    ...
    conn.Close();
}
```

At the end of the `using()` block, `conn.Dispose()` is called automatically even if an exception occurs within the block.